# IWAE0006E Archive is not a valid WAR File because the deployment descriptor can not be found (case sensitive): WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, war, web.xml, ear

I do have a **web.xml** file in my **WAR**. The structure of the **WAR** is also fine. But when I add it to my **EAR** and deploy I get the following error message in the console

**[4/18/16 16:08:28:372 IST] 00000027 wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl openNestedArchive - module An error occurred while opening a nested archive: IWAE0006E Archive is not a valid WAR File because the deployment descriptor can not be found (case sensitive): WEB-INF/web.xml**

I tried closing my Eclipse, cleaning and building all the projects, but no luck.

What else could be the issue here? Can you some one help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Small tip: if you have such option, move away from EAR archive to a single WAR. Much less potential problems.

When it comes to the original question: it looks you have your `war.xml` file in a wrong location.
If you are not using any build tool, just Eclipse IDE - and you don't know how to assembly a proper WAR archive - you may for example create a new `Dynamic Web Project` in Eclipse and look at its structure.

It may also be an issue with Eclipse, so you can delete all Eclipse-specific files (like `.settings`, `.project`) and then import your projects from scratch.